# ASP.NET Page Cannot be Null when Repeater Data is null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am facing an issue with Repeater in ASP.NET now.

I am binding data to the repeater which is inside a div for which visibility is false and display is none. When I bind data to the repeater I get two cases:

CASE 1:

When query returns some data. In this case I do not get any error and every thing runs fine.

CASE 2:
When query returns blank. This time I get Page Cannot be null error.
(Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.)

Please find the code which runs on that button click.

```
int RowCount = 0;
string cmd = "SELECT PrjB.Prj_ID, POB.ExpType as ExpType, TExp.Expenditure_ID AS ExpID, ISNULL(PrjB.Amount_Allocated, 0) AS
  BudgetAllocated, ISNULL(POB.AmtAllocated, 0) "
  + "AS BudgetAvailedPO, ISNULL(NonPOB.AmtPaid, 0) AS BudgetAvailedNonPO FROM v_ProjectBudgetAllocated AS PrjB LEFT OUTER JOIN "
  + "v_POBudgetAllocated AS POB ON PrjB.Prj_ID = POB.Proj_ID AND PrjB.Expenditure_Type = POB.ExpType LEFT OUTER JOIN "
  + "v_NonPOBudgetAvailed AS NonPOB ON NonPOB.PrjID = PrjB.Prj_ID INNER JOIN T_Expenditure AS TExp ON POB.ExpType = TExp.Expenditure_Type "
  + "WHERE (PrjB.Prj_ID = '" + PrjID + "') ORDER BY ExpID";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, myConnection);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCmd);
da.Fill(ds);
RowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

poStep3.Visible = true;
poStep3.Style["display"] = "block";

if (RowCount == 0)
{
  poStep3.InnerHtml = "<b>Cannot Create Purchase Order. There is no budget allocated to this Project </b>";
}
else
{
  PrjBudgetDetails.DataSource = ds;
  PrjBudgetDetails.DataBind();
}
```

The ASPX Code for the div is:

```
<div id="poStep3" class="formStep" runat="server" visible="false" style="display:none;">
  <fieldset>
    <span id="poDataEntryHead" class="formHead" runat="server">
      Enter PO Details 
    </span>
    <legend id="poDataEntryInstructions" class="frmInstructions" runat="server">
      Please fill
      all the texts in the fields. All fields are mandatory
    </legend>
    <div id="MessageDiv" runat="server" class="formMsg">
    </div>
    <div class="fieldgroup">
      <asp:Label ID="LbPOID" runat="server" Text="PO ID:" CssClass="formFieldLabel" AssociatedControlID="POIDText">
      </asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="POIDText" name="PrjIDText" runat="server" CssClass="formInputField">
      </asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Label ID="POIDTextDsp" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"
      CssClass="formFieldLabel" Style="display: none;">
      </asp:Label>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldgroup">
      <asp:Label ID="LbPOTitle" runat="server" Text="PO Title:" CssClass="formFieldLabel"
      AssociatedControlID="POTitleText">
      </asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="POTitleText" name="POTitleText" runat="server" CssClass="formInputField">
      </asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Label ID="POTitleTextDsp" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="formFieldLabel"
      Visible="false" Style="display: none;">
      </asp:Label>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldgroup">
      <asp:Label ID="LbPODesc" runat="server" Text="PO Description:" CssClass="formFieldLabel" AssociatedControlID="PODescText">
      </asp:Label>
      <textarea id="PODescText" name="PODescText" cols="50" rows="6" runat="server" class="formInputField" />
      <asp:Label ID="PODescTextDsp" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="formFieldLabel"
      Visible="false" Style="display: none;">
      </asp:Label>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldgroup">
      <asp:Label ID="LbPOIssueDateText" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="PO Issue Date:" CssClass="formFieldLabel">
      </asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="POIssueDateText" name="POIssueDateText" runat="server" CssClass="formInputField">
      </asp:TextBox>
      <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
      </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
      <asp:CalendarExtender ID="POIssueDateText_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="POIssueDateText"
      Format="MM-dd-yyyy">
      </asp:CalendarExtender>
      <asp:Label ID="POIssueDateTextDsp" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="" Visible="false" CssClass="formFieldLabel" Style="display: none;">
      </asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldgroup">
      <asp:Label ID="LbprjBudgetInfoHead" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Project Budget data:" CssClass="formFieldLabel">
      </asp:Label>
      <span id="prjBudgetInfoHead" class="formHead" runat="server">
        Project Budget Details
      </span>
      <span id="prjBudgetInfoInstructions" class="frmInstructions" runat="server">
        The
        current program budget status.
      </span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="fieldgroup">
      <table class="tblDispData">
        <asp:Repeater ID="PrjBudgetDetails" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
          <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
              <th class="thDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="LbExpType" runat="server" Text="Expenditure Type" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                Font-Bold="true">
                </asp:Label>
              </th>
              <th class="thDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="LbAllocatedBudget" runat="server" Text="Allocated Budget" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                Font-Bold="true">
                </asp:Label>
              </th>
              <th class="thDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="LbAvailedBudget" runat="server" Text="Available Budget" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                Font-Bold="true">
                </asp:Label>
              </th>
              <th class="thDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="LbRequestedBudget" runat="server" Text="Budget Requested" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                Font-Bold="true">
                </asp:Label>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="ExpTypeText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ExpType") %>' CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"AssociatedControlID="BudgetRequestedText">
                </asp:Label>
              </td>
              <td class="tdDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="BudgetAllocatedText" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("BudgetAllocated") %>' CssClass="LbTblDataDisp" AssociatedControlID="BudgetRequestedText">
                </asp:Label>
              </td>
              <td class="tdDataDisp">
                <asp:Label ID="BudgetAvailableText" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAllocated")) - Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAvailedPO")) - Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAvailedNonPO")) %>' CssClass="LbTblDataDisp" ClientIDMode="Static" AssociatedControlID="BudgetRequestedText">
                </asp:Label>
              </td>
              <td class="tdDataDisp">
                <asp:TextBox ID="BudgetRequestedText" runat="server" dataKey='<%#Eval("ExpID") %>' dataValue='<%#Eval("ExpType") %>' CssClass="tblDataInput" dataAmount='<%#Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAllocated"))  Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAvailedPO")) - Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAvailedNonPO")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <span id="Span1" class="frmInstructions" runat="server">
              Please enter zero(0) if not
              requesting budget for any particular expenditure. The currency is INR. 
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="POSubmitBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit Budget" CssClass="formNext" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="POSubmitBtn_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="POGoToHomeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="POGoToHomeBtn_Click" Text="Home" CssClass="formNext" Visible="false" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Its been few hours since I am banging my head at Google. Looks like I am stuck here and need some expert help to move ahead.

Thanks in Advance.
-Himanshu

Comment: Perhaps setting `poStep3.InnerHtml` is the problem since it contains server controls. Try setting `poStep3.Visble = false` instead.

Comment: BTW, that inline query should be avoided to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the person who gave answer here removed them or some thing else. But one guy posted the answer two days back and it worked.

The solution was to have another hidden div and make it enable instead of updating innerHTML of the current div.